# Incremental quotient limit

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{h}=?$

I wanted to know if you could help me with this exercise, I know that you are using the incremental quotient.

The book's solution:

Here you have to think a little. They are giving us a limit that is very similar to the derivative by definition at point $x_0 = 3$, but it is exactly this derivative, because it would be like this:
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\Rightarrow f'(3)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}$$
As in the limit $f(3)$ appears, we can write it as $kf'(3)$, and that name we give to the exercise limit.

Compare $f'(3)$ and $kf'(3)$ using the definition and the limit they give us: (if they are equal, $k = 1$, and we are left with $f '(3)$, otherwise, it will be some other solution)
$$f'(3)=kf'(3)\Rightarrow \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{h}\Rightarrow \lim_{h\to 0}3+h=\lim_{h\to 0}3+2h$$
We have two limits that tend to $0$. We replace and we have left:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}3+h=\lim_{h\to 0}3+2h\Rightarrow 3+0=3+2\cdot 0\Rightarrow 3=3
$$
Then, the limits are equal, so $k = 1$. In this way, the answer is $f '(3)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big Hint**: $$\frac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{h}=2\cdot\frac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{2h},$$ and $h\to 0$ if and only if $2h\to0.$

Comment: Thanks! So, this limit is equal to $2\cdot f'(3)$, right?

Comment: In a book, I have seen that the good answer is $f'(3)$. I don't know if it is well solved.

Comment: Bingo! Can you justify it?

Comment: Well, if $f'(3) happens to be $0,$ then that's true, but otherwise the book's answer is not correct.

Comment: Then I do $t=2h$ and $h\to 0$ if and only if $t\to 0$, and I will have $2\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+t)-f(3)}{t}=2f'(3)$

Comment: That's the idea. You should probably prove it rigorously, though, in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta,$ *especially* since the book has a different answer.

Comment: I have put the solution of the book in the question. I don't know if it is well solved.

Comment: The book's solution is incorrect. They assume the (false) result that they're trying to prove, then instead prove the (true but irrelevant) result that $$\lim_{h\to0}3+h=\lim_{h\to 0}3+2h.$$ What book is this?

Comment: This solution would be correct?: I deduce its function $y=3+2x$ in $x_0=3$. Then \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{3+2h-9}{h}=2=f'(3). It's not a book, I got it out of a few determined notes, but it always comes with errors, thanks anyway, it was strange to me the proposal he made.

Comment: Are you familiar with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs? If not, I'd stick with your previous solution (setting $t=2h$), as that one doesn't make sense. You might come prepared with an example. For instance, if $f(x)=3+2x,$ then $f'(3)=2.$ However, $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{9+4h-9}h=\lim_{h\to0}4=4=2f'(2).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What is $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{2h}?$$

What can you conclude from this limit?

Comment: In a book, I have seen that the good answer is $f'(3)$. I don't know if it is well solved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{h}=       \lim_{2h\to 0} 2\dfrac{f(3+2h)-f(3)}{2h} = 2f'(3) $$